# How to wrap text in css?

Tags: html, css, alignment

the text just overflows  into a vertical direction.How to make it  wrap?
css for the div:

```
.taskdescription{
  display:block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #673ab7;
  width: 300px;

}
```

what its looking like.

[image]

Comment: add HTML & CSS Code here

Comment: If you set the width to 300px and then make the parent narrower than 300px, it's not the text element that's overflowing, it's the element overflowing out of its parent. (So it doesn't wrap, because it's taking up the 300px you told it to)

Comment: @LaljiTadhani does the css look wrong?why exactly this happens...sorry cant post the the whole code.

Comment: @DebadityaSinha ok No problem, How can identify what the problem

Comment: It wraps just fine with the code you posted: https://jsfiddle.net/woeuv2tj/
There's something going on on a higher level in your code that overrules or contradicts these CSS statements.

Comment: @DBS thanks but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I used white-space: no wrap which was overriding this properties.So changing it  to white-space:normal solved my problem.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The overflow-wrap has attributes: normal, break-word, anywhere. When you change with word-wrap it will work.

The easy-squeeze example is on [w3school-overflow-wrap](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_overflow-wrap)
You mismatched the overflow ( this is for scroll ) with word-wrap or overflow-wrap.

The first one is for text and the second is for long-word.
This is a confused bunch of CSS properties because overflow is doing something else. Try to decode it in the w3school example - works the same as a fiddle.

[word-wrap - example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_play_word-wrap)
[overflow - example scrolling-bar](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `overflow:auto` code snippet.

Comment: Please add more clarity.